# How to tell FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to use a specific cookie path?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Why is there no `strCookiePath` parameter in `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`?

If you pass a `strCookiePath` to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`, the `SignOut()` method does no longer work (it "deletes" the cookie with the Web.config's cookie path).

How to tell `SignOut()` to use a specific `strCookiePath`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to use custom SignOut method if you are using custom path. Method will manually expire the cookie. Something like:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieValue);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
cookie.Path = /*the path you used in FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()*/;
cookie.Expires = new System.DateTime(1999, 10, 12); /*some past date*/
cookie.Domain = /*custom domain if configured*/;  
context.Response.Cookies.RemoveCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: That's what I already did ... don't like it though ... * hoping for something better *

Answer (score -1):

Users can still browse your website because cookies are not cleared when you call FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and they are authenticated on every new request. In MS documentation is says that cookie will be cleared but they don't, bug? Its exactly the same with Session.Abandon(), cookie is still there.
I solved this by NOT setting the domain of the cookie.  If i just left it blank, and only set expires date, then both FF and IE handle logout properly.

```
 private static void SignOut()
 {
     var myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
     myCookie.Domain = "mysite.com";
     myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
 }

 protected void lnkLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Session.Clear();
     //Session.Abandon();
     //Session.RemoveAll();
     //Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
     HttpContext.Current.User =   new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
     FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
 }
```

Comment: Did you simply copy this from another answer to get reputation? I have no `Domain` set. Also: FormsAuthentication.SignOut DOES clear the cookie, look at the code!